# Правильность написания слова «галантный»

Tags: грамотная-речь, краткое-прилагательное

"Галантлив не в меру, хотя нелюдим".

Возможно ли такое написание слова – *галантлив*?

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим в словарях: [галантный](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), краткая форма – *галантен*. Слова «галантливый» нет.

*Он галантен, любезен, очень элегантно одевается* (Сати Спивакова. Не всё. 2002).
*Главный, как всегда, был галантен* (И. Грекова. Перелом. 1987).
*Он элегантен, галантен, строен, ― камзол, шпага…* (М. И. Цветаева. Чердачное. 1919-1920)